# Dependence of linear algebra theorems of the commutativity of the field.

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

In the linear algebra course I took vector spaces where introduced with a (commutative) field. The classical theorems are proven under this assumption.

However, I was wondering what implications it would have if one would only consider skew fields. I have looked it up and the commutativity is used in several proofs such as "every set of $n+1$ vectors is linearly dependent in a $n$-dimensional vector space".

Do all the classical results still hold? Or are their major modifications?

(I'm asking this question in the context of affine geometry, where every affine space of dimension $\geq 3$ can be considered as a vector space with a skew field)

Comment: Commutativity is not relevant in the statement you quote. You can't define the determinant, for instance (or you can, but with quite different properties).

Comment: Godement's *Algebra* is helpful on this question. (I could have sworn there'd been a Dover reprint, but apparently not.)